# Meaning of docker-compose exit code?

Tags: docker, exit, docker-compose, exit-code

For example, if I force a container to stop with `kill`, then `docker-compose ps` to check my containers, I get ***State*** as `Exit 137`. And with `docker-compose stop` I get `Exit 1`/`Exit 0`

As there are no documentation for exit code, can anyone please explain to me the meaning of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has not so much to do with docker as with the system it is running on. If you take a look in this table of [reserved exit codes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) for bash, you can see the line:

```
128+n   Fatal error signal "n"  kill -9 $PPID of script $? returns 137 (128 + 9)
```

Which corresponds to the 137 you mention. It is 128 + 9 (SIGKILL), which you can see in the [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page. Normally a 0 means a clean exit and 1 there was something wrong, these two can suffice for a programmer. They can however range from 1-255, including the reserved ones mentioned above.

This is just a short answer as I am not an expert on the subject, you can find more on this unix.stackexchange thread on [default exit code when process is terminated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99112/default-exit-code-when-process-is-terminated) or perhaps someone here can give a much more elaborate answer than mine.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion :) i get everything i need now

Comment: nice explanation,

Answer (score 2):

It seems you might be running out of memory. It's a Linux standard as mentioned here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

---

Error Code **128**       : Invalid argument to exit

---

Error Code **128+n**    : Fatal error signal "n"    kill -9 $PPID of script $? returns 137 (128 + 9)

---

> Error 137 in Docker denotes that the container was ‘KILL’ed by ‘oom-killer’ (Out of Memory). This happens when there isn’t enough memory in the container for running the process.
>
> ‘OOM killer’ is a proactive process that jumps in to save the system when its memory level goes too low, by killing the resource-abusive processes to free up memory for the system.

Here's [a little more info](https://bobcares.com/blog/error-137-docker/)